# MySql return empty result when one of table for JOIN is not any data

Tags: mysql

with below Sql query i can get result successful when all of tables has data, but in this my query when `transactions` table has not any saved data and its empty my query return empty result, but i want to get null or empty columns data

```
SELECT transactions.id, 
       userEwallets.ewalletNumber, 
       userEwallets.currencySymbol, 
       transactions.money, 
       transactions.transactionType, 
       b.username AS toUser, 
       a.username AS sender 
FROM transactions
   JOIN userEwallets ON transactions.ewalletId = userEwallets.id
   LEFT JOIN users AS b ON b.id = transactions.toUserId
   LEFT JOIN users AS a ON a.id = transactions.fromUserId
WHERE transactions.userId = 37
```

when its not empty i get this result:

```
id  ewalletNumber       currencySymbol  money   transactionType toUser  sender
95  SHIRR9373036569     IRR 20          1       1                   amin
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a dummy table with one row. The other tables should be left joined to it.

```sql
SELECT transactions.id, 
       userEwallets.ewalletNumber, 
       userEwallets.currencySymbol, 
       transactions.money, 
       transactions.transactionType, 
       b.username AS toUser, 
       a.username AS sender 
FROM (select 1) dummy
   LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.userId = 37
   LEFT JOIN userEwallets ON transactions.ewalletId = userEwallets.id
   LEFT JOIN users AS b ON b.id = transactions.toUserId
   LEFT JOIN users AS a ON a.id = transactions.fromUserId
```

You can allways use a subquery instead of a table name if you give it an allias. Note that you have to move the WHERE condition for the left joined table into the ON clause - Othewise MySQL will convert it to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Thanks sir, problem solved, whats `(select 1) dummy` ?

Comment: Its a dummy derived table with one row and one column. Try `select * from (select 1) dummy` - and you will see.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry sir, in this query `userEwallets.ewalletNumber` and `userEwallets.currencySymbol` in `userEwallets` table are not empty, but in this query i get null for them and `id` too

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Try to use only LEFT JOIN (see the update).

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish that, you should use another table to be the first one. The way you are doing it, if there are no records in the `transactions` table then there would be nothing to join with.
So, use a table that always has records and `LEFT JOIN` it with the others.
Try this:

```
SELECT transactions.id, 
   userEwallets.ewalletNumber, 
   userEwallets.currencySymbol, 
   transactions.money, 
   transactions.transactionType, 
   b.username AS toUser, 
   a.username AS sender 
FROM users AS b
LEFT JOIN transactions ON b.id = transactions.toUserId
LEFT JOIN users AS a ON a.id = transactions.fromUserId
JOIN userEwallets ON transactions.ewalletId = userEwallets.id
WHERE transactions.userId = 37
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `where` condition here. `where transactions.userId = 37`. If there is no data in transactions table, that `where` condition will fail and hence returns no data

Comment: its necessary condition for my query, i can/t remove that, because i dont have one user in database

Comment: @tux-world If there is no data with in table, then it means there is no data that matches the criteria mentioned in where clause and so you are not getting any data

Comment: yes, its correct, but i want to get columns with empty data not empty result